# Removing array element does not work

Tags: php, session

there is a $_SESSION array that holds the ID of user's currently selected products (which are in the cart). Now, when the user sees his bill, he want to remove an item (product) from his cart, I have put him a link to do so. but the script does not work. 
I have configured a `$_GET['itemid']` in the URL and by using it, I `unset()` that array element.

BUT it does not work. What should I do? Here is my code

```
function remove_from_cart($stack_id) // stack_id is the id of the item in cart array ($_SESSION)
{   

    for($i=0; $i < count($_SESSION['add-to-cart-item']); $i++)
    {
            if($_SESSION['add-to-cart-item'][$i] == $stack_id)
            {
                unset($_SESSION['add-to-cart-item'][$stack_id]);    
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: first of all try the debug your session using `print_r` and make sure is `$_SESSION['add-to-cart-item']` actually an array

Comment: i dont see what the for loop is doing

Comment: You compare `...[$i]` but you unset `...[$stack_id]`...

Comment: and also avoid using `$i < count($_SESSION['add-to-cart-item']` in your statement it will execute every time. consider using ` for($i=0, $count = count($_SESSION['add-to-cart-item']); $i < $count; $i++)`

Comment: sute I do that. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your code

```
if($_SESSION['add-to-cart-item'][$i] == $stack_id)
{
   unset($_SESSION['add-to-cart-item'][$stack_id]);    
}
```

you find that $stack_id equals $_SESSION['add-to-cart-item'][$i] and not $i

which means that you need to unset $_SESSION['add-to-cart-item'][$i].

good luck

Answer (score 1):

You should unset with `[$i]`

`unset($_SESSION['add-to-cart-item'][$i]);`

Comment: simple solution. I had tried. But a part of code differed at that instance. Thanks very much